# Mysql query, need some help. XOR operation

Tags: mysql

I have a table Books with isbn and name of books, and I have a table orders with oisbn(foreign key) and ocid (foreign key, customer ID of he who has bought the book).
A

I want to list the cids of those customers who have ordered only ocid=123 or ocid = 567,NOT both. Kind of like XOR.

How do I accomplish this in mysql? I've been thinking for a long time and I can't figure it out.

Comment: put your schema with sample data on http://sqlfiddle.com and desired output with what you have tried.

Comment: Err, not sure this makes sense. You want the customers who are either customer 123 or customer 567, but who are not both customers? Are you looking for customers who have orders oisbn 123 or oisbn 567, but not both?

Comment: Did you try XOR operator in mysql? Explain how it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT
foo
FROM
bar
WHERE ocid IN (123, 567)
GROUP BY customerId
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```